# assigning on-click values from svg graphic in html using thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-boot, svg, thymeleaf

here is what i want to do:

1. click on svg graphic field (my goal is to hardcode value to this field)
   -this value will held two parameters, wchich will correspond index of two dimensional array
2. pass this value to my methods by controller

here is a piece of my HTML

```
<a xlink:href="#"><circle vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" cx="325.4916807491179" cy="-130" r="36" fill="rgb(235,235,235)"/></a>
                <text x="325.4916807491179" y="-130"
                      text-anchor="middle"
                      stroke="red"
                      stroke-width="1px"
                >0, 4
                </text>
```

in this example i want to pass "0" and "4"

[html and svg output looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzlLk.png)

i don't have any idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

column and row are variables passed as @PathVariable

```
<a th:href="@{/showmap/{column}/{row} (column=${0}, row=${4})}"><circle vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" cx="325.4916807491179" cy="-130" r="36" fill="rgb(235,235,235)"/></a>
                <text x="325.4916807491179" y="-130"
                      text-anchor="middle"
                      stroke="red"
                      stroke-width="1px"
                >0, 4
```